# Logout as root on mac terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, root

The terminal prompt on my Mac currently looks something like this: `hostname username %`

As far as I understand, the `%` means I'm logged in as root.

However, I went into my mac system preferences and checked, and it looks like I have root user disabled.

Not sure what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The root user in the System Preferences is something you would log out and log in as. The % does not mean you are "logged in as root"; it doesn't mean anything. If the value of PS1 ends in `%` then that is what you will see.

Comment: Also this is not a _programming_ question. How to use your Mac etc. is something for SuperUser or AskDifferent probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of macOS Catalina Apple switched from **bash** to **zsh** as the default Shell.

The percent sign `%` is **zsh**'s prompt.

You're not logged as root.